# Web Page goes Slow After being open for few Minutes and is sorted with a refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working in a project that is built in ASP.Net MVC that will display data on the screen, and every time one of the labels is clicked it should change colours. This project is meant to be displayed in more that one screen at the same time, and both screens be able to use it. The problem is that after running this for few minutes, one of the screens will start to be incredibly slow, and it after a hard refresh it will be back to normal but not for long. I have tried to uses both direct calls to the database and entity framework model, but so far no luck...
Chrome's dev Console shows this, I don't know if this might help...

[image]

```
        function refreshCheckTimers() {
            $(".check-timer").each(function () {

                //Longest timer overall
                var dish_id = $(this).attr("data-longestDish");

                var mainbody = $(this).closest(".check-footer").siblings(".check-mainbody");
                var prepTime = parseInt($(mainbody).find("[data-uniqueID=" + dish_id + "]").attr("data-prepTime")); //in seconds
                var dish_status = parseInt($(mainbody).find("[data-uniqueID=" + dish_id + "]").attr("data-status"));
                var activeCourse = $(mainbody).find("[data-uniqueID=" + dish_id + "]").attr("data-course");
                if (activeCourse == "mains" || activeCourse == "sides") {
                    activeCourse = "MCSI";
                }

                var anyDishCooking = false;
                if (activeCourse == "starters") {
                    anyDishCooking = $(mainbody).find(".dish-details:not(.summary)[data-course=starters][data-status=" + CheckStatus.get("COOKING") + "]").length;
                } else if (activeCourse == "MCSI") {
                    anyDishCooking = $(mainbody).find(".dish-details:not(.summary, [data-course=starters], [data-course=pastry])[data-status=" + CheckStatus.get("COOKING") + "]").length;
                } else if (activeCourse == "pastry") {
                    anyDishCooking = $(mainbody).find(".dish-details:not(.summary)[data-course=pastry][data-status=" + CheckStatus.get("COOKING") + "]").length;
                }


                var cookingStartTimeString = $(mainbody).find("[data-uniqueID=" + dish_id + "]").attr("data-cookingStartTime");
                var cookingStartTime = new Date(cookingStartTimeString);
                var endTime = new Date(cookingStartTime.getTime());
                endTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() + 1000 * prepTime);
                var currentTime = new Date();

                var diff = endTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime();
```

```
        function DisplayCheck() {
           
            var TableNumber = $(".table-entry").val();
            var checkDate = new Date().toISOString();
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("DisplayCheckForTable", "KitchenScreens")',
                contentType: "application/json;",
                data: JSON.stringify({ TableNumber: TableNumber }),
                success: function (result) {
                    for (const c in result.lstChecks) {
                        placeCheck(result.lstChecks[c]);
                    }

                    
                },
                complete: function () {
                    setTimeout(DisplayCheck, 1000);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.warn(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

placeCheck

```
        // Contains all operations performed on check for display
        function placeCheck(check) {

            var checkElement = jQuery.parseHTML(check);
            
            checkElement = styleCheck(checkElement);    //give check appropriate borders and dish colors

            var currCheckID = $(check).attr("id");

            var checkContent = $(checkElement[1]).html();

            //also need to update expanded if its open
            var modalOpen = $("body [data-check-id='" + currCheckID + "']").length;
            
            populateExpandedCheck(checkContent, currCheckID);    //refresh expanded check
            // Set scroll position of check mainbody for expanded check
            var expandedScrollPos = $("body [data-check-id='" + currCheckID + "']").attr("scrollPos");
            expandedScrollPos = (typeof expandedScrollPos === 'undefined') ? 0 : expandedScrollPos;
            $("body [data-check-id='" + currCheckID + "']").find(".check-mainbody").scrollTop(expandedScrollPos);
            

            
        }
```

Thank you in advance
Happy coding!

Comment: @Diogo Can you share the code of the view? Also is the site built with `ASP.Net` or `ASP.Net MVC`. Your tags and the question is not aligned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is ASP.NET MVC. I will edit the post and add a code snippet to it

Comment: @Rahatur Is this enough. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `placeCheck` and what does it do? Also when are you calling the `DisplayCheck` and `refreshCheckTimers` functions from?

Comment: Can you post the content of PlaceCheck method ?

Comment: @Rahatur refreshCheckTimers is called throughout the code, and it refreshes what is displayed every second

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the followings:

- Use synchronous in your ajax call. Set `async: false` property.
- On ajax complete event increase the delay to call the `DisplayCheck` again. I am not sure if 1 second is enough to get the data from the server and process it before the next trigger happens. May not feel the difference on your local machine but on production server. set to 2000 ms?
- From the sample code it is still not clear where and when the `refreshCheckTimers` is called but try to limit the call to the `refreshCheckTimers` function.
- Instead of parsing page html every time you have new data, I would suggest to maintain a javascript object list from which you can refresh the UI. i.e. update the data in ajax call and then render the UI from the list ignoting what was rendered previously.

Comment: is has definitely helped, but it is still takes arround 3 seconds for the state to change

Comment: @DiogoSilva what do you mean by `3 seconds for the state to change`?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I have not explained my self well, this is a project that will display orders from a restaurant into a kitchen screen. The chef will be able to click every single item of the order and when he clicks an item it should change its state. The problem I am having is that if an item is clicked it takes about 3 seconds to update its status.